# Can an array refer to itself

Tags: php, associative-array

I have this associative array, where `key2` and `key5` are always going to have the same value as `key1`. Is it possible to set their values by referring to the array itself or any other suggestions to remove the value duplication?

```
$arr = array(
   'key1' => 'some value',
   'key2' => 'some value', //same as key1 and will always stay as key1
   'key3' => 'some other value',
   'key4' => 'yet another',
   'key5' => 'some value'  //same as key1 and will always stay as key1
);
```

Comment: If they will always be the same, why do you need it in there 3 times?

Comment: @barfoon because I check the array by key. I need to be able to still do `$arr['key3']` even though internally my script treats it as `$arr['key1']`.

Answer (score 10):

You could apply a [`&` reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) after the array has been declared:

```
$arr = array(...);
$arr["key2"] = & $arr["key1"];
$arr["key5"] = & $arr["key1"];
```

Comment: +1'ed , thanks for the tip never realized one could do this in an array.

Comment: hmm, although I am still pondering whether what practical application this approach may serve, I admit this is something new to me. Up you go! ++1

Comment: Note that if you `unset($arr['key1'])` and then `$arr['key1'] = 'foo'` the other two keys will not be updated.

Comment: ^ Likewise of course if you were to `unset($arr["key5"])` - that severes the reference in either case.

Comment: @mario, This looks good, thanks. Can it be improved this way: `$arr["key2"] = $arr["key5"] = & $arr["key1"];` ?

Comment: @switch: Unfortunately no. The second assignment operator only transfers the value, not the reference. So you need to spell it out explicitely for PHP.